# Written pattern not matching with string Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm validating text field for following data pattern "I-MH-ABCD-ABC-1222";

Following is a RegEx I've written and it is not working.

```
var router_added_sap = "I-MH-ABCD-ABC-1222";
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{1}\-[a-zA-Z]{2}\-[a-zA-Z]{4}\-[a-zA-Z]{3}\-\d/;

if(!router_added_sap.match(pattern))
{
   alert("Please Enter Right SAP-IDasa");
   return false;
}
```

Though user write correct pattern script is giving me an alert message.

Comment: Is it because your first variable is `couter_added_sap` but you are checking against `router_added_sap`?

Comment: Also, you're only validating against a single digit `\d`

Comment: sorry my Bad. question updated..

Comment: No need to escape slashes in regex.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I'm not getting an alert message with your snippet.

Comment: Your code works. Moreover, if you don't need the matched sub string, you can just use `pattern.test(router_added_sap)`, it returns boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely no need to escape the dashes. You also need to group each of these together. If these are being used in a single field by itself then I would recommend making sure to check for the start of the string (^) and the end of the string ($) and apply the ignore case flag at the end (i). The (+) just at the end is a quantifier that will check for 1 or more digits and grab all of them.  So I would rewrite it as such.

```
var router_added_sap = "K-MH-ABCD-ABC-1222";
var pattern = /^([A-Z]{1})-([A-Z]{2})-([A-Z]{4})-([A-Z]{3})-\d+$/i;

if(!router_added_sap.match(pattern))
{
   alert("Please Enter Right SAP-IDasa");
   return false;

}
```

http://www.regexr.com/ is great for helping build Regular Expressions. I also keep a great cheat sheet printed off on my desk that I found here: http://cheatography.com/1/cs/5/